# cannot create any C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7 Enterprise running on a x86 box. I cannot create any C++ project from VS although I can create C# project. On the new project dialog I press OK button and nothing happens. I don't get any error but no solution or project is created either. Not sure if it helps but I log in as Administrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the thing called C++ runtimes which is required by VS to run properly?
I guess the idea to reinstall is good.
This will even repair some missing or corrupt which may have been accidentally deleted or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not check the C++ language option during installation. If you re-run the Visual Studio installer and check the C++ language option (maybe choose custom setup to make sure you see the option and are able to include it), everything will run file.

In case you already did that, there might be a problem with the C++ project type registration in VS. Please come back to this forum if you still have problems after re-installation.